# Convergence issue tuning parameters for logistic regression to maximise recall

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, hyperparameter

I'm currently working on a fraud detection project and I am trying to do a gridsearch with a logistic regression to find good values for parameters "C" and "class_weight". The dataset is very unbalanced (500:1) and I want to maximise "recall" (I think) to minimize the false negatives. I read that weighting the classes differently can help with this.

The problem I'm having is that the grid search is just telling me to use the smallest C and the largest class_weight no matter what values I try, which leads to a useless model as it is severely overfitting, which I thought C was supposed to stop as it increases regularization. I guess weighting the classes is a bad idea? It seem's like increasing the class_weight is like the MSE issue where adding more complexity always reduces the MSE.

What I want to know is how I should go about finding a good model to minimize recall since this approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Don't use class weights. Optimise for logloss ( in gridsearch) and then use roc curve to decide the best threshold for your application

Comment: Logistic regression parameters are optimized by optimizing the gold standard optimality criterion: the likelihood function (possibly w/penalization).  The likelihood function **must** respect how the data were sampled, and any attempt to make up new weights to apply represents a misunderstanding of statistical principles that is based on a false belief that imbalanced samples are problematic.  Once the optimum parameter estimates are computed, you can evaluate the model on other metrics such as predictive discrimination.  See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).

Comment: I think I see my mistake now. So the idea is to fit a model with the loss function because that's the only way to get a fit where the parameters are unbiased. Then using recall to pick the best model will add some bias in model selection, but the parameters themselves are still unbiased, unlike if I use recall to fit the model in the first place.